# How to define an iterator interface type?

Tags: c#

I've written a class that implements `IEnumerable<T>`. I have a method that returns `MyClass`. If I try to  `yield return` from within that method, the compiler tells me "... cannot be an iterator block because ... is not an iterator interface type".

So, how can I define my own interface iterator type? Does it have to be "abstract" (can't have any methods defined)?

What I want to do is write a bunch of chainable methods, so every method should return an instance of `MyClass`. But I need `MyClass` to be some kind of enumerable. Rather than using some underlying data type, I was hoping I could just `yield return` everywhere.

---

@Oded:

```
class SharpQuery : IEnumerable<HtmlNode>
{
    public SharpQuery Find(string selector)
    {
        foreach (var n in this)
        {
            // filter the results
            yield return node;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant bits of your code?

Comment: 9 years on, and there is an answer: IAsyncEnumerable is available in C# 8.0. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, that's not possible. To see why consider that you have a class `Zoo` that implements `IEnumerable<Animal>` but also has lots of other members. A `Zoo`is an `IEnumerable<Animal>` but not necessarily vice versa - a sequence of animals is just a sequence of animals. There's no zoo keeper, no shops, no entrance fee or any of the other things that makes a zoo a zoo.

When you use `yield return x` the return type cannot be `Zoo` because you don't have a zoo - you just have a sequence of animals.

What you can do instead is to call it as `new Zoo(foo())` where `foo` returns an `IEnumerable<Animal>` and add a constructor to `Zoo` that accepts an `IEnumerable<Animal>`.

Comment: Even if `Zoo` doesn't have any data, just methods?

Comment: If you only have methods you could implement them as extension methods on `IEnumerable<Animal>`. Then I think you get what you wanted - you can easily use yield, and you can have specialized methods on your sequences.

Comment: I need a constructor though... which would yield just one item I guess. Then I guess I could just use a public function for that instead. I have to think about this a bit more... if I really want to constrain myself to a stateless class... it's a neat idea though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think when you use `yield return x` you will be producing an `IEnumerable` of X type. So in your case it would be IEnumerable

Inheriting from one class would not automatically mean it will implicitly cast itself to that type. So if you write

```
class SharpQuery 
{
    public IEnumerable<HtmlNode> RepositoryItems { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<HtmlNode> Find(string selector)
    {
        foreach (var n in this.RepositoryItems)
        {
            // filter the results
            yield return node;
        }
    }
}
```

it works. IEnumerable is not same as SharpQuery.

Comment: Good catch. Yes actually it is a stripped version. SharpQuery does not implement IEnumerable actually, but the return of Find will work.
I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

According to section 8.2 of the C# Language Specification Version 4.0:

> A block that contains one or more `yield` statements is called an iterator block. Iterator blocks are used to implement function members as iterators.

Section 10.14 specifies that the return type of an iterator must be one of the following:

- `IEnumerator`
- `IEnumerable`
- `IEnumerator<T>`
- `IEnumerable<T>`

According to section 10.14.4, invoking an iterator does not immediately execute the code in the iterator block. Instead, an enumerator object that implements the following interfaces is created and returned:

- `IEnumerator`
- `IEnumerator<T>`
- `IDisposable`

The enumerator object is typically an instance of a compiler-generated nested class with private accessibility.

Comment: I think I wanted to return something that implemented one of those interfaces, rather than the interface itself.

Comment: Per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx the C# spec is installed with Visual Studio in `Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC#/Specifications/1033` . Change visual studio version as appropriate, 14.0 for VS2015, etc